# Increase size of menu item

Tags: android

I have created menu using xml.I want to change the size of the menu items and also the

background color. Is it possible to make changes in the menu.Please suggest me,any help

would be appreciable.

Comment: You can refer this... it will certainly help you!!

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you check this [Customizing Background and Text color in Options Menu Android](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2011/04/19/customizing-background-and-text-color-in-options-menu-android/)